# Unknown service zeus-admin running on my server

Tags: apache, tomcat, zeus

I used `nmap` to check which ports are open on my server it showed

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
9090/tcp open     zeus-admin
```

now port 9090 is supposed to listen for  `apache tomcat`. What is this zeus-admin ?
how I start my `apache tomcat server` ?

Comment: quick google found this http://www.securiteam.com/unixfocus/3B5QCR5PPK.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zeus Web Server is a proprietary web server for Unix and Unix-like platforms.

ZWS seems to be dead since it hasn't been updated since January 2010, and the company no longer offers a similar server solution.

It's probably fine to just kill it, and remove it from operation as it's mostly just a security risk by now.

Comment: _"It's probably fine to just kill it"_ is terrible advice. Neither you nor op know/knew what service was running on that port.

Answer (score 6):

It is also the default listed name when nmap'ing it. The actual service listening to that port doesn't have to be, it's what is usually the default service running at that port.

Answer (score 1):

Zeus is sometimes used as an embedded web server for things like admin consoles. If you have the OpenFire XMPP server installed, you will find the configuration UI tools running on port 9090 (http://localhost:9090).

Comment: BUT see Lukas's answer.